# Is this Normalised Multiple Choice Quiz Program Database Design OK?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am designing a simple multiple choice quiz program in python where the user signs in and takes a multiple choice quiz of 5 questions (selected randomly from a table of questions) and the program ends the quiz with a display of their questions, their answers, the correct answers and their score.

Is the following database design correct? I have three tables, one for the student, one of the questions (options and answer) and one for the quizzes taken.

The real question I suppose is whether or not it is OK to have the same foreign key (questionsID) inserted into the quiz table on 5 separate occasions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you don't want the same question making it in there multiple times. To that end I assume you've made sure each question has a unique identifier and is excluded by the code from being used more than once per quiz per student. If such is the case, then yes, it should work fine.

To clarify: If you have two questions; say for example "What is the second letter of the alphabet?" assigned as qID0001 and a second question, "What is the twenty-sixth letter of the alphabet?" assigned as qID0005, then QuestionsID should be set to randomly call qIDxxxx and make sure that one is not reused.

Comment: Yes, I would ensure that the same question could not be selected twice in any one quiz. Great, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I made following schema based on your description:

Student (id, first, second, age, class)

Question (id, text, FK correctOptionId)

Option (id, text, FK question)

Quiz (id, FK idStudent, finalScore)

QuizQuestions (id, FK quizId, FK questionId)

Answers (id, FK questionId, FK optionId, FK studentId, correct)

There's some redundancy, which can be removed. I believe, it's slightly more scalable for the future and most important thing is, it avoids multiple FK issue you mentioned

Comment: Thanks for your time. So going back to my question, is having the same foreign key multiple times in the same table actually an issue? You said your suggested schema avoids the multiple fk issue, but is there still an issue providing there are appropriate validations in place when selecting questions at random to ensure the same question doesn't get asked twice?

Comment: AFAIK it should be possible